# How to tell the difference between a Flags enum and ordinary enum?

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

Is there any way to test reflectively if an enum is a `[Flags] enum` or if it's a regular `enum`?

I need the application to behave slightly differently if the enum is a Flags enum than if it's not a Flags enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test for attribute existence via reflection:

```
System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(t);
var isFlags = attrs.Any(attr => attr is FlagsAttribute);
```

Or:

```
var isFlags = typeof(MyEnum).GetCustomAttributes<FlagsAttribute>().Any();
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw(v=vs.80).aspx

**[OP Edit:]**

this worked, but the syntax is slightly wrong. This is correct:

```
var isFlags = myEnum.GetType()
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the attributes of the enum with reflection and see if the FlagsAttribute is used.